# Android button effect does not work

Tags: android, xml

I want to use 2 pictures for one button to make a effect when user click it.
I think I did properly but, the effect does not work.

Specifically, the button background set to camera_button_after.jpg which is meant for pressed state and does not change when it is clicked.

Could you tell me what's wrong? I'll be very appreciated.

**Here is the main_frame.xml which contains buttons.**

main_btn1.xml, main_btn2.xml, main_btn3.xml are selectors.
Those three selectors have same structure and also same problem..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button001"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/main_btn1"
    android:text="   Mood"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button002"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/main_btn2"
    android:text="    Mood Lists"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button003"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/main_btn3"
    android:text="   Help"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the main_btn1.xml

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/camera_button_before" />

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/camera_button_after"/>

</selector>
```

One more question is..I think the eclipse doesn't fully recognize the pictures and xml files. I cleaned the project few times and reboot the eclipse but it they still have question mark like below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the similar problem. I tried the below code. I did get this solution from stack overflow itself, but do not have its link for reference. So writing the code snippet for xml in drawable folder. Do remember to provide the right image names :)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/image1" />
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/image2" />
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/image3" />
<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/image4" />
</selector>
```

Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I think it is eclipse problem. I made some extra question below the last one, can you look at that and advise me how to get rid of that question marks?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your xml with this.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item 

    android:drawable="@drawable/camera_button_before" />

<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/camera_button_after"/>
```

Comment: I did it before and now again..but it didn't work.. I think it is eclipse problem. I made some extra question below the last one, can you look at that and advise me how to get rid of that question marks?

Comment: Make sure your button is clickable. and have you set on click listener on buttons?